# Dot product of vector with camera's local positive x-axis?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I would like to detect if a cube is in the right half of the camera's view:

[image]

I'm trying to do this with geometry nodes. Here's what I have so far:

[image]

**(Bottom half of this image)**
I normalize the cube's position, bring it to view-space and perform a dot product on it (with the camera's local x-axis?) and output the dp value as an attribute.

**(Top-left of this image)**
I use this dp value to color the cube in the scene.

**(Top-right of this image)**
There's a camera with its local axis orientation annotated on the screen as well as the cube I mentioned before.

[image]

The problem I'm having here is I don't think I'm using the correct camera's positive x-axis when performing the dot product. When I move the cube around the camera on the x-y plane, the cube turns black when it's on the right side of the camera (meaning the dp <= 0) and when it's on the left side of the camera, it turns white (dp > 0), which is the complete opposite of what I want.

Here's a video showing the incorrect result:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQzbW.jpg

I know I can simply add a "Math" node after the "Separate XYZ" and multiply it by -1 to flip it but I want to get the correct positive x-axis without having to flip it.

**Edit:** Please ignore the incorrect use of the "Separate XYZ" into the dot product node; it inputs a vector with a value of (X,X,X) into the dot product. I thought it was going to input (X,0,0) into it. I fixed that tiny mistake by putting a "Combine XYZ" (using (X,0,0) as the values) after the "Separate XYZ". But this is a moot point because if you look at @RobinBetts reply below, I need to use "Vector" and "Vector Rotate" for the local x-axis instead anyway.

Answer (score 5):

Is this group any good to you? It stores, on the modified object's points, whether the object is camera-right or camera-left.

[image]

The 'Rotation' outputs of various nodes have three components, but *they are not  Cartesian vectors*. They are collections of three angles. So Dot-Products of those don't make any conventional sense. To get the Camera-X *vector*, take **(1,0,0)** and rotate it by the camera's rotation.

[image]

Comment: I made 2 changes to get it to somewhat working properly (it's still not correct though):

1) it seems my view transform was incorrect. For the translation, I have to subtract. https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/2037/correct-view-space-transform

2) I applied your "Vector" and "Vector Rotate" nodes

Here's what my nodes currently look like:
https://imgur.com/a/PaH7Fhm

Here are my results: you can see that the dot product value becomes zero way before the cube reaches the middle of the camera:

https://imgur.com/a/Sa7gKei

Comment: Sorry about the formatting issue above. I'm not sure how to put the sentences on a new line. I used shift-enter and that looks fine but once I add the comment, it seems to ignore formatting. :(

Comment: Hi, @Sam ! np about the formatting. Comment markdown is limited, I can not get this group, as shown, to fail at my end, nor can I understand why it should, unless your camera is carrying a shift, or something? Try [this file](https://blend-exchange.com/b/2QddeJbR/), and let us know? It's a bit of a mystery, to me ...

Comment: This group does give a result for object-origin L/R. It would need tweaking for point L/R. I see your GN group is on a 3rd-party object.. is that necessary?

Comment: Not sure what "carrying a shift" means. Yeah. The 3rd-party object is necessary, that's why I'm trying to transform it to view space. (Object-origin L/R is fine. Don't need point L/R.)

Comment: If [this one](https://blend-exchange.com/b/RyWDWDzS/) works for you, we can edit it into the answer.

Answer (score 4):

If you like, you can do it with shader nodes only:

[image: Camera Data View Vector -> Separate X -> Greater Than 0]

The [View Vector](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/input/camera_data.html#outputs) is the normalized vector from the camera to the shading point, in camera space.

In camera space, the right half of the screen is just X > 0.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can only do it in the Geometry Shader. The only reason why I output the dot product value to the shader is just to visualize/confirm the value. I did learn a lot about the "Camera Data" node from you though! I didn't know it and its View Vector existed. Thanks for that! :)